# Passing a parameter when uploading CSV files and parsing to database (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, csv

I'm trying to allow users to import a CSV file to an application's database. I've been following the rails casts on [importing csv and excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel). I'm not sure how I can pass in a parameter that is not found in the excel or csv file.

For example I'm using devise for authentication and instead of the user having to input the user_id on the file being uploaded I want the user_id to be set to the current_user.id. How can I do this?

My code below:

**Model's method for importing the file**

```
 def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Gear.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

**Controller Action**

```
  def import
    Gear.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Gears Uploaded"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to just pass in the user ID into the `import`-method like this:

Model:

```
def self.import(file, user_id)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    Gear.create! row.to_hash.merge(user_id: user_id)
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def import
  Gear.import(params[:file], current_user.id)
  redirect_to :back, notice: "Gears Uploaded"
end
```

Be aware that you will overwrite existing `user_id`-columns in the CSV, but if I understand you correctly this is intended behavior.